# Binding a WPF TreeView control to a KeyValuePair<string,object>

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I would like to have my treeview built up of KeyValuePair and only display the key as the header. I have googled this and cant find any examples.

So far I have:

```
KeyValuePair<string, object> str = new KeyValuePair<string,object> (cores.Keys[i], cores.Values[i]);
TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem();
tvi.Header = str;
```

then in the xaml:
`<TreeView Name="tvCores" Grid.Column="0" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown" DisplayMemberPath="Key"/`>

Please let me know if you need anymore information

Comment: how are your bindings defined ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code behind, you just need to do this :

```
KeyValuePair<string, object> str = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(cores.Keys[i], cores.Values[i]);
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
list.Add(str);
tvCores.ItemsSource = list;
```

Now, your ItemsSource is a list of KeyValuePair so the path work, before the ItemsSource was a TreeViewItem so the path couldn't work.